# Introductory (online) texts on Bayesian Network.

Tags: reference-request, bayesian-network

I would like to ask for some recommendation of introductory online texts on Bayesian Network.
What I am searching for is some accessible and instructive text not necessarily covering the subject in great depth, but explaining the main ideas. Simply an accessible introductory text (possibly online) for a fast orientation in the subject.

Comment: [tag:reference-request] should not be used as a standalone tag; see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2498/the-meta-tags). I've added [tag:probability], since I was not able to find a more appropriate tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a small list of references:

1. [Kevin Murphy's A Brief Introduction to Graphical Models and Bayesian Networks](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/Bayes/bnintro.html)
2. [Kevin Murphy's Phd Thesis](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/Thesis/thesis.html)
3. [Michael Jordan's Graphical Models](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jordan/papers/statsci.ps)
4. [Collection of papers appearing in Michael Jordan's Learning in Graphical Models](http://aivalley.com/jordancol.html)